# Replace a base64 value in a file in unix

Tags: sed, perl, base64

I have a problem, I have a file test.txt that has a content like this:

```
objectClass: CPM1
objectClass: CPM2
objectClass: CPM3
objectClass: CPM4
objectClass: CPZ
objectClass: CP04s
objectClass: CP0A
objectClass: CP11
entryDS: 1
nodeId: 21
createTimestamp: 20211014155438Z
modifyTimestamp: 20220313041228Z
MSISDN: 353834079137
IMSI: 272050103105233
NAM: 0
CDC: 1423
IMEISV:: U1RQJgAkQiE=
AUTHINFO: 0
CSP: 11
SUBSCSPVERS: 20
RSA: 20
SUBSRSAVERS: 19
APNID1: 4
```

Every time the text IMEISV:: is found I want to replace in that file the value after IMEISV:: (in this case U1RQJgAkQiE=) with the result of the following function:

```
base64 -d | od -t x8 -An | rev
```

If I do in unix an echo would be like this:

```
echo U1RQJgAkQiE= | base64 -d | od -t x8 -An | rev
```

The result would be 3545056200422412

So at the end in the file, the value U1RQJgAkQiE= should be 3545056200422412. Like this:

```
objectClass: CPM1
objectClass: CPM2
objectClass: CPM3
objectClass: CPM4
objectClass: CPZ
objectClass: CP04s
objectClass: CP0A
objectClass: CP11
entryDS: 1
nodeId: 21
createTimestamp: 20211014155438Z
modifyTimestamp: 20220313041228Z
MSISDN: 353834079137
IMSI: 272050103105233
NAM: 0
CDC: 1423
IMEISV:: 3545056200422412
AUTHINFO: 0
CSP: 11
SUBSCSPVERS: 20
RSA: 20
SUBSRSAVERS: 19
APNID1: 4
```

Can someone please let me know how to do it with sed/perl...? I'm really a newbie with unix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
unpack("h*", decode_base64($_))
```

where `decode_base64` is provided by the perl `MIME` module, ex.:

```
$ perl -MMIME::Base64 -pe 's/IMEISV:: \K(.*)$/unpack("h*", decode_base64($1))/e' test.txt
objectClass: CPM1
objectClass: CPM2
objectClass: CPM3
objectClass: CPM4
objectClass: CPZ
objectClass: CP04s
objectClass: CP0A
objectClass: CP11
entryDS: 1
nodeId: 21
createTimestamp: 20211014155438Z
modifyTimestamp: 20220313041228Z
MSISDN: 353834079137
IMSI: 272050103105233
NAM: 0
CDC: 1423
IMEISV:: 3545056200422412
AUTHINFO: 0
CSP: 11
SUBSCSPVERS: 20
RSA: 20
SUBSRSAVERS: 19
APNID1: 4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot steeldriver, this option is a lot faster than using a sed when working with a huge file. And works like a charm too

Answer (score 3):

`sed  's/\(IMEISV::\)\(.*\)/echo -n \1" ";echo \2\| base64 -d \| od -t x8 -An\|rev  /ge ' input.txt`

The trick is the e switch.
Output:

```
objectClass: CPM1
objectClass: CPM2
objectClass: CPM3
objectClass: CPM4
objectClass: CPZ
objectClass: CP04s
objectClass: CP0A
objectClass: CP11
entryDS: 1
nodeId: 21
createTimestamp: 20211014155438Z
modifyTimestamp: 20220313041228Z
MSISDN: 353834079137
IMSI: 272050103105233
NAM: 0
CDC: 1423
IMEISV:: 3545056200422412 
AUTHINFO: 0
CSP: 11
SUBSCSPVERS: 20
RSA: 20
SUBSRSAVERS: 19
APNID1: 4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was lost trying to add the echo to the sed command and of course I didn't even knew about the e option. I suppose that's to use the output of echo as input of the function.

Comment: I tried solution from steeldriver because although using this sed works, it takes a really long time when we talk about a 7GB ldif file. But thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

One idea using  `sed` would be to execute your command above within the `sed` replacement using `printf` to print to first matched group without a new line.

```
$ sed "s/\(IMEISV::\)\(.*\)/printf '\1 ' ; echo \2 | base64 -d | od -t x8 -An | rev/e" input_file
objectClass: CPM1
objectClass: CPM2
objectClass: CPM3
objectClass: CPM4
objectClass: CPZ
objectClass: CP04s
objectClass: CP0A
objectClass: CP11
entryDS: 1
nodeId: 21
createTimestamp: 20211014155438Z
modifyTimestamp: 20220313041228Z
MSISDN: 353834079137
IMSI: 272050103105233
NAM: 0
CDC: 1423
IMEISV:: 3545056200422412
AUTHINFO: 0
CSP: 11
SUBSCSPVERS: 20
RSA: 20
SUBSRSAVERS: 19
APNID1: 4
```

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
#------------------
#  base64 in sed
#------------------
set -u

#> format string printf
fmt='%s%s\n'

#> bit, sextet, & octet regex
bit='[01]'
sextet="${bit}{6}"
 octet="${bit}{8}"; byte=$octet

#> base64 charset
b64='/[:alnum:]+'
declare -a b64_chars=({A..Z} {a..z} {0..9} + /)

#> user-defined helper function(s)
oneLine() {
  # collapse stdin into one line
  paste -sd'\0' -
}

esc_rhs() {
  # make stdin pkuggable
  # on the rhs of a s///
  sed -e '
    s:[\/&]:\\&:g
    $!s:$:\\:
  ' -
}

dec2bin() {
  # create an array of size 2^$1
  # Usage: dec2bin 6
  # creates array d2b as:
  # underscore for clarity only
  # $d2b[0] => "000_000"
  # $d2b[1] => "000_001"
  #        ...
  # $d2b[63] => "111_111"

  eval "d2b=($(yes '{0,1}' | sed "$1q" | oneLine))"
}

#> build the encoding lookup table
encode_tbl=$(printf '%s\n' "$(
dec2bin 6
i=0
for c in "${b64_chars[@]}"
do
  printf "$fmt" "$c" "${d2b[$i]}"
  (( i++ ))
done
)" | esc_rhs)

#> build the decoding lookup table
decode_tbl=$(printf '%s\n' "$(
dec2bin 8
for dec in {0..255}
do
  hex=$(printf '%02x' "$dec")
  bin=${d2b[$dec]}
  printf "$fmt" "$bin" "$hex"
done
)" | esc_rhs)

#######> main()
sed -E "
  s/^IMEISV::\s*//;t base64
  b
  :base64
  s/[^${b64}]//g
  /^\$/d
  H;z;x;G

  s/\$/$encode_tbl/
  :encode
  /\n\n/!{
    s/((\n)[${b64}])(.*\1(${sextet}))/\4\2\3/
    b encode
  }

  s/\n.*//;:pad
  /^(${octet})+\$/!{
    s/\$/0/;b pad
  }
  # chunk it in 8-bit portions
  s/(${octet})/& /g
  G;s/\$/${decode_tbl}/;t decode
  :decode
    s/(${octet}) (.*\n\1([[:xdigit:]]{2}))/\3\2/
  t decode

  s/\n.*//
  s/([[:xdigit:]])([[:xdigit:]])/\2\1/g
  s/00?\$//
  s/^/IMEISV:: /
" file
```